# sleekxmpp : ejabbered : not able to connect to sever

Tags: python-2.7, xmpp, ejabberd, jabberd2

I just installed ejabbered and sleekxmpp. I am trying to run a sample program as mentioned http://sleekxmpp.com/#here-s-your-first-sleekxmpp-bot . Using ejabbered admin I created a sample user.

```
Web Admin->Virtual Hosts->selected test@test.com->Users->Added new user name password
```

So my modified code is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ideally use optparse or argparse to get JID,
    # password, and log level.

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

    xmpp = EchoBot('test_user@test.com', 'password')
    xmpp.connect()
    xmpp.process(block=True)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 6120: Stream Feature: STARTTLS
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 6120: Stream Feature: Resource Binding
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 3920: Stream Feature: Start Session
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 6121: Stream Feature: Roster Versioning
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 6121: Stream Feature: Subscription Pre-Approval
DEBUG    Loaded Plugin: RFC 6120: Stream Feature: SASL
WARNING  DNS: dnspython not found. Can not use SRV lookup.
DEBUG    DNS: Querying test@test.com for AAAA records.
DEBUG    DNS: Error retreiving AAAA address info for test@test.com.
DEBUG    DNS: Querying test@test.com for A records.
DEBUG    Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5222
ERROR    Could not connect to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5222. Socket Error #111: Connection refused
DEBUG    No remaining DNS records to try.
DEBUG    Waiting 2.27851082363 seconds before connecting.
WARNING  DNS: dnspython not found. Can not use SRV lookup.
DEBUG    DNS: Querying test@test.com for AAAA records.
DEBUG    DNS: Error retreiving AAAA address info for test@test.com.
DEBUG    DNS: Querying test@test.com for A records.
DEBUG    Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5222
ERROR    Could not connect to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5222. Socket Error #111: Connection refused
DEBUG    Waiting 1.85516992239 seconds before connecting.
DEBUG    No remaining DNS records to try.
DEBUG    Waiting 3.72981095414 seconds before connecting.
DEBUG    Starting HANDLER THREAD
DEBUG    Loading event runner
DEBUG    Stopped event runner thread. -1 threads remain.
DEBUG    Stopped send thread. -1 threads remain.
DEBUG    Quitting Scheduler thread
DEBUG    Stopped scheduler thread. 0 threads remain.
$ ^C
```

Please let me know how I can rectify this?

===Update====

I am using Wi-Fi n/w so when I give ifconfig command I get the below output:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:f9:ed:cd:64:51  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4043 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4043 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:606641 (606.6 KB)  TX bytes:606641 (606.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:17:31:de:e4:d9  
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a617:31ff:fede:e4d9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:48717711 (48.7 MB)  TX bytes:6499289 (6.4 MB)
```

The 10.0.0.2 is my router address which is different from xx.xx.xx.xxx that is displayed in the program debug logs - is it something to do with this IP configuration - if so where do I modify by what value?

== UPDATE ===

Debug level logs shows me the below info : [**failed authentication for test@test.com**]:

**Further Jabber client states error related to certificate with ignore option.**

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:12:49 ===
I(<0.37.0>:ejabberd_app:72) : ejabberd 2.1.10 is started in the node 'ejabberd@test.com'

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
I(<0.542.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.1832>) Accepted connection {{127,0,0,1},39872} -> {{127,0,1,1},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = "<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"test.com\" version=\"1.0\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" xml:lang=\"en\" >"

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = [60,63,120,109,108,32,
                                                       118,101,114,115,105,
                                                       111,110,61,39,49,46,48,
                                                       39,63,62,60,115,116,
                                                       114,101,97,109,58,115,
                                                       116,114,101,97,109,32,
                                                       120,109,108,110,115,61,
                                                       39,106,97,98,98,101,
                                                       114,58,99,108,105,101,
                                                       110,116,39,32,120,109,
                                                       108,110,115,58,115,116,
                                                       114,101,97,109,61,39,
                                                       104,116,116,112,58,47,
                                                       47,101,116,104,101,114,
                                                       120,46,106,97,98,98,
                                                       101,114,46,111,114,103,
                                                       47,115,116,114,101,97,
                                                       109,115,39,32,105,100,
                                                       61,39,"4262884447",39,
                                                       32,102,114,111,109,61,
                                                       39,
                                                       "test.com",
                                                       39,
                                                       [" version='","1.0",
                                                        "'"],
                                                       [" xml:lang='","en",
                                                        "'"],
                                                       62]

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='TQ2JFyRoSa70h2G1bpgjzuXb2sU='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>">>

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = "<starttls xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls\"/>"

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,0,1377521048483549}, Size=51
M=25.5, I=4.907


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = []

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,983.8342528646939,
                                    1377521048509468}, Size=0
M=0.0, I=-19.024


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = []

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,491.91712643234695,
                                    1377521048510450}, Size=0
M=0.0, I=93.656


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = []

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,245.95856321617347,
                                    1377521048604127}, Size=0
M=0.0, I=6.537


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = "<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"test.com\" version=\"1.0\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" xml:lang=\"en\" >"

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,122.97928160808674,
                                    1377521048610682}, Size=161
M=85.7742263697187, I=1.123


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = [60,63,120,109,108,32,
                                                       118,101,114,115,105,
                                                       111,110,61,39,49,46,48,
                                                       39,63,62,60,115,116,
                                                       114,101,97,109,58,115,
                                                       116,114,101,97,109,32,
                                                       120,109,108,110,115,61,
                                                       39,106,97,98,98,101,
                                                       114,58,99,108,105,101,
                                                       110,116,39,32,120,109,
                                                       108,110,115,58,115,116,
                                                       114,101,97,109,61,39,
                                                       104,116,116,112,58,47,
                                                       47,101,116,104,101,114,
                                                       120,46,106,97,98,98,
                                                       101,114,46,111,114,103,
                                                       47,115,116,114,101,97,
                                                       109,115,39,32,105,100,
                                                       61,39,"665429700",39,
                                                       32,102,114,111,109,61,
                                                       39,
                                                       "test.com",
                                                       39,
                                                       [" version='","1.0",
                                                        "'"],
                                                       [" xml:lang='","en",
                                                        "'"],
                                                       62]

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:08 ===
D(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='TQ2JFyRoSa70h2G1bpgjzuXb2sU='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>">>

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = "<auth xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\" mechanism=\"SCRAM-SHA-1\">biwsbj1zYXR5YSxyPTg2YWZmYTQxNzZjMmMxMzc1NDg1N2NmNGU1ZDcwNTAzNTBiMDU2YWQ4NTc4ZmMxNA==</auth>"

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,0,1377521048612173}, Size=162
M=81.0, I=15096.97


**=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
I(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:649) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.1832>,#Port<0.1860>},<0.545.0>}) Failed authentication for test@test.com**

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
D(<0.546.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = <<"<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure>">>

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
D(<0.545.0>:ejabberd_receiver:320) : Received XML on stream = "<abort xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\" />"

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-08-26 18:14:23 ===
D(<0.545.0>:shaper:61) : State: {maxrate,1000,5.365311472890604,
                                    1377521063709153}, Size=50
M=25.067246793407225, I=1.775

^C
```

Comment: The sleek logs mention that it cannot find the dnspython module, and cannot do SRV record lookups. This will leave you unable to connect to some (many) servers. I suggest you fix this, and see if your problem still remains.